# Obtain items from a list inside a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have this list:

```
li = [['class_a', '45%'], ['class_b', '20%', '30%', '40%']]
```

How can I obtain the percentages from the list? The desirable output should be shomething liek this:

```
new_list = ['45%'], ['20%', '30%', '40%']
```

Thaks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is consistent that the first element in each sublist will be the class, then you can just remove that element from each list:

```
li = [['class_a', '45%'], ['class_b', '20%', '30%', '40%']]

for l in li:
    l.pop(0)

print(li)
```

Output:

```
[['45%'], ['20%', '30%', '40%']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work for any case, whether the first element is classname or last element is classname, or any other variables are there in the list.

```
li = [['class_a', '45%'], ['class_b', '20%', '30%', '40%']]

answer = []
for i in range(0, len(li)):
    temp = []
    temp_li = li[i]
    for j in range(0, len(temp_li)):
        if "%" in temp_li[j]:
            temp.append(temp_li[j])
    answer.append(temp)

print(answer)
```

Output : `[['45%'], ['20%', '30%', '40%']]`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
result=[]
for i in li:
    temp=[]
    for ele in i:
        if re.search(r"(\d+)%",ele):
            temp.append(ele)
    result.append(temp)

Output : [['45%'], ['20%', '30%', '40%']]
```